# Pass Generic Method With Parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, action, func

I have the following code which allows me to pass a method as a parameter.

```
Items = Scroll(Items, SearchCriteria, Execute(() => ItemService.GetItemsAsync(SearchCriteria)));
```

My `Scroll` class then looks like this

```
public InfiniteScrollCollection<T> Scroll<T>(InfiniteScrollCollection<T> source, BaseCriteria baseCriteria, Task<List<T>> serviceCall)
{
    this.BaseSearchCriteria = baseCriteria;

    source = new InfiniteScrollCollection<T>
    {
        OnLoadMore = async () =>
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            // load the next page
            this.BaseSearchCriteria.PageIndex = source.Count / this.BaseSearchCriteria.PageSize;

            var items = await serviceCall;

            IsBusy = false;

            // return the items that need to be added
            return items;
        },
        OnCanLoadMore = () =>
        {
            return source.Count < this.MaxCalls;
        }
    };

    DownloadDataAsync(source, serviceCall);

    return source;
}
```

My problem arises on the line `this.BaseSearchCriteria.PageIndex = source.Count / this.BaseSearchCriteria.PageSize;`

I need to increase `PageIndex` which is a property in the parameter used in the `GetItemsAsync`. I can change the `BaseSearchCriteria` `PageIndex` property but the  `await serviceCall` doesn't allow me to pass it as a parameter.

So is there a way for me to be able to change the `serviceCall` parameter?

I have tried changing the `scroll` parameters to

```
public InfiniteScrollCollection<T> Scroll<T>(InfiniteScrollCollection<T> source, BaseCriteria baseCriteria, Func<BaseCriteria, Task<List<T>>> serviceCall)
```

which then allows me to pass the updated criteria to `serviceCall`

```
var items = await serviceCall(this.BaseSearchCriteria);
```

But then I don't know how to pass the method/func into the initial code shown in the first code snippet.

EDIT: I've change the initial code to this and it seems to be working.

```
Items = Scroll(Items, SearchCriteria, 
            new Func<BaseCriteria, Task<List<Data.Entities.Item>>>(x => ItemService.GetItemsAsync(SearchCriteria)));
```

Comment: You don't need those `new Func...` declaration. You can just use `, x => ...` as lambda. It is also important not to pass `Task` like you did at the first place because most `Task` start immediately while we actually need it to run when we need it, which is why we need to use `Func<Task>`.

Comment: I've removed the new Func part now. Its not related to this question but now Im getting duplicate values.

Comment: " but the  await serviceCall doesn't allow me to pass it as a parameter" - I'm a little confused. You already passed it as a parameter when you called `Execute(() => ItemService.GetItemsAsync(SearchCriteria))`... Are you trying to take into account that its quite possible that the consumer might use two different SearchCriteria objects in your initial method call?

Comment: When I did it that way I couldnt make changes to the SearchCriteria inside the Scroll class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Items = Scroll(Items, SearchCriteria, x => ItemService.GetItemsAsync(SearchCriteria));
```

I used to following code to solve my problem.

Comment: Why are you declaring x but not using it? Are you sure this does what you want? Did you maybe want `ItemService.GetItemsAsync(x)`?

Comment: Yeah Im sure its doing what I want it to do. I've been using the application since and everything is working great.

Comment: But my question then is why are you creating a parameter and not using it? This would do the same as `() => ItemService.GetItemsAsync(SearchCriteria)`...